# Category/ies with product and coproduct defined for any pair of objects

Tags: category-theory

What is the name for a category such that the product of two objects is always defined?
What is the name for a category such that the COproduct of two objects is always defined?
Does there exist a name for a category where BOTH are defined? What is it?
I'm thinking about categories such as Set of Vect.

Comment: Usually, this is discussed in the context of limits since products are a special case of limits and limits can often be expressed as a quotient of products. A category where all limits exist is called complete and one where all colimits exist is called cocomplete.

Comment: In Set, more than just the product of any pair exists: the product of any small family exists... in any case, if a category has binary products, then it has all finite products. It’s called “a category with finite products.” Likewise, “a category with finite coproducts.”

Comment: @DanielApsley: Hmmm... no, you do talk about just products, quite a bit (since, for example, Freyd’s Adjoint Functor Theorem only requires the existence of arbitrary products and equalizers). I agree that there is the more general notion, but there is certainly discussion of categories in which we only ask about finite products, or about $\lt \alpha$ products, or about small products.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Good point. I suppose that's just where I've seen it the most. It might be the closest thing that has a name other than its literal description though.

Comment: I'd just say something like "$\mathcal{C}$ admits finite products" (or "coproducts" or both as appropriate).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin "Arbitrary products and equalizers" is equivalent to "arbitrary limits".

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Right; because you can construct limits by using products and equalizers.

Comment: Categories admitting finite products are often called "cartesian"; those admitting finite coproducts are called "cocartesian"; and those admitting both are called "bicartesian".

Comment: @varkor: nLab advises against [cartesian](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+category).

Comment: @RobArthan: it depends on the context. "Cartesian" is used very commonly in computer science to mean having finite products; whereas in an area like topos theory, "cartesian" usually means having finite limits.

Comment: @varkor: sure, I expect that's why nLab recommends against using "cartesian". And it's why I would recommend using an unambiguous phrase like "admitting finite products".

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Just nitpicking: a category can have binary products without having all finite products if it lacks a terminal object (the 0-ary product). Same for coproducts and the (lack of) initial object. I am not aware of a name for a category with all binary products but no terminal object.

Comment: @Pece: If I understand the nitpick, you are agreeing binary products implies all finite products over nonempty indices, but it may not include the empty product. I agree to that important techncial point.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm turning my comment into an answer so that the question may be resolved.)

A category admitting finite products is often called *cartesian*. However, especially in topos theory, "cartesian" is also used to mean a category admitting finite limits. To disambiguate, you can say [cartesian-monoidal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cartesian+monoidal+category). Dually, a category admitting finite coproducts is often called *cocartesian* or [cocartesian-monoidal](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cocartesian+monoidal+category). A category admitting both finite products and finite coproducts is sometimes called [bicartesian](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bicartesian+category).

I do not believe there are common names for categories admitting solely binary (co)products, rather than nullary and binary (co)products, hence all finite (co)products.